# Force transformation problem

Tags: ros, transform, robotic-arm, kinematics, force

I have the following set-up:

[image]

I read force and torque values in sensor frame, but I want to transform the to tool frame. I have the following equation:

[image]

where:

[image]

This last matrix shoul be 6x6, but if I resolve [image] I have a 3x1 matrix, so I dont understand how can I get the 6x6 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The term $P_{SORG}^{T}$ in the transformation represents the **skew-symmetric matrix, derived from the position vector**. Here's how you put a vector $P = [p_x, p_y, p_z]$ in its skew-symmetric matrix form:

$$
%P_{SORG}^{T} \times =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -p_z & p_y \\
p_z & 0 & -p_x \\
-p_y & p_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is now a 3X3 matrix. When this matrix is multiplied by the rotation matrix, it will give you the remaining 3X3 bottom-left part to build your goal 6X6 force transformation matrix from the sensor frame to the tool frame.

Comment: It makes sense. I have another question. I have integrated the force sensor in robot flange, and the I have attached a tool . I know HTM betweebn flange and tool, but I dont know the HTM between tool and sensor. How could I calculate it?